# Rotating /48 block in Puppeteer for requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, ipv6

I have a VPS with a /48 ipv6 block, let's say `1234:1234:1234::/48`.

Normally if I want to make a GET request with axios that rotates through the IP block I would do the following:

```js
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const options = { localAddress: utils.getRandomIPv6("1234:1234:1234::/48"), family: 6 }
const httpAgent = new http.Agent(options)
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent(options)
axios.get('https://example.com/', { httpAgent, httpsAgent })
```

I was wondering if there's a way that I can rotate through the block for web scraping purposes with puppeteer.

Comment: Please do not just make up IP addresses. IANA has set aside IP ranges for such things. For IPv4, there are three `/24` ranges: `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`. For IPv6, there is a `/32` range: `2001:db8::/32`. Using networks and addresses in those ranges lets people know that you are giving examples, not using actual addresses.

Comment: I do not think you really understand the magnitude of the numbers involved with IPv6. For example, with just one standard `/64` IPv6 network, there are `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` addresses. At 1,000,000 addresses per second, it would take over 584,542 _years_! A `/48` prefix would take 65,536 times as long.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you for the reply. I didn't know that there is a pre-set range for example IP addresses. And I was just wondering if there's a way that I can get a random IP from the `/48` block when using puppeteer to request a webpage, not necessarily rotating through all of the IPs in the block.

Comment: A prefix such as a `/48` prefix is delegated to be subnetted into standard `/64` networks. There are 65,536 standard `/64` IPv6 networks in a `/48` prefix. You use IPv6 Prefix Delegation to assign the networks. [Using IPv6 networks of sizes other than `/64` can break IPv6 features.](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/34172/8499) IPv6 addresses are really just 128-bit unsigned integers in network order (big-endian). You can randomly choose an IID (last 64 bits of an IPv6 `/64` address), convert it to the text representation, and append it to the `/64` network address.

Comment: @RonMaupin I see, what I’m struggling with right now is trying to use the random address in puppeteer. Normally I would change the `localAddress` property to specify from what IP address send the request, however, I have yet to find a way to do it with puppeteer